# Show that we can always find a real basis for the eigenspace of a real eigenvalue of a real matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a matrix in $\Bbb R^{n\times n}$, if $\lambda$ is a real eigenvalue of $A$, show we can find a real basis for the eigenspace pertaining to $A$.

I am new to this, so anyone can help show a hint where we can start to deal with such problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvectors are the solutions of the linear system $(A-\lambda I)x=0$.

$A-\lambda I$ is a real matrix. because $A$ is a real matrix and $\lambda$ is real.

Solving a linear system does not go outside the field of scalars.

In particular, solving a linear system defined by a real matrix gives you real solutions.